# Indirect multi-level smart pointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Say, given the following smart pointer scheme:

```
 weak_ptr<Style> A -> weak_ptr<Style> B -> shared_ptr<Style> C
```

Can you change the second weak_ptr (B) to point (observe) a new shared_ptr (C) in a way that would still make the first weak_ptr (A) see the new changed shared_ptr (C)?

Hope that makes sense. I would like to stay away from raw pointers, given the safety weak_ptr can provide in this case.

**Edit:**

After re-reading boost documentation I realize that weak_ptr operator= essentially just copies another weak_ptr and not actually makes it observe another weak_ptr. So you can't have this kind of indirection without raw pointers?

**Edit 2:**

To expand on my problem: I have a `Label` and a `Glyph`. A `Label` is a container for `Glyph`s. A label has a `shared_ptr<Style>` and Glyphs have a `weak_ptr` to this style. My intend is to allow quick changes of a style without actually iterating over all label glyphs. So I was thinking of having another "active" style (like a style pencil) in a `Label` and making all glyphs point to that pencil thing. So whenever I need a style change I simply re-assign pencil to a new Style object. Can this be done with only smart pointers or I need to mix in a raw pointer somewhere?

Comment: I am sorry, but to me this makes no sense - can you express your intent in code?

Comment: Updated the question with more info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objects have shared_ptr to a Style and it is the same Style then between them they handle the lifetime of this Style object. Note however that they share the reference to the same object so if you modify the style, all of them will now have a pointer to the modified style.

If you have some table of stylesheets somewhere, and this is the main container that outlives your items, then you don't need your items to have smart-pointers unless there is a danger that they might need to keep a reference to this style and use it even after it is removed from the table or the table disappears.

Generally, forget about the hows for the moment and think about the whats in terms of object ownership.

Comment: Your answer made me look at my Glyph design again. And yep, it doesn't really make sense for glyph to observe any style object whatsoever. A glyph needs a style for drawing only - so that can be passed around with a function argument.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need raw pointers.
It is worth considering what behaviour pattern you need.
Some suggestions are:

1. Glyphs are internal to label, they are not exposed and die when label dies.
   Style properties get changed but the style instance is constant.
   In this pattern just using one level of shared_ptr in each class is the simplest solution.
   There is no concern that a Glyph will extend the lifetime of the style and all shared_ptrs will point to the same instance.
2. Glyphs are internal to label, they are not exposed and die when label dies.
   Style instance can be changed.
   In this case label can hold a proxy to a style (I think your concept of a pencil was a proxy to a style) e.g. a simple class that has a single shared_ptr to a style as a member.  The proxy should be held in a shared_ptr. Each Glyph can hold a shared_ptr to an instance of the proxy.
3. Glyphs are not internal to label, they are exposed and should be allowed to access the style even if label has died.
   The designs in #1 and #2 will still work.
4. Glyphs are not internal to label, they are exposed but should not cause the lifetime of style to be longer than the lifetime of label.
   In this case follow the pattern in #1 or #2 except the Glyphs should use weak_ptr to the style(#1)  or proxy(#2) instance instead of a shared_ptr to the style/proxy instance.

If you wanted to you could implement the proxy by having a shared_ptr to a shared_ptr  to a proxy (rather than writing a custom class) but this may make the code hard to follow. Note if nesting in this manner be careful with the template type, for the second level you actually want a `shared_ptr<shared_ptr<Foo>>` rather than a `shared_ptr<Foo>`.